# Why is the page guide removing ability to scroll table?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-joyride library and I'm trying to make a page guide for my tabke but it removes the abillity to scroll horizontal and vertical when adding PageGuide.

pageGuide.js

```js
export default function PageGuide() {
    return (
      <Joyride
        run={true}
        callback={() => null}
        steps={[
          {
            content:
              "This column MUST remain empty and untouched in order for your data to work properly.",
            target: ".react-grid-Cell:nth-child(1) "
          },
          {
            content:
              "Beginning from this column and continuing to the right, you may name the columns to letters. Every column name will be turned into a label for your chart.",
            target: ".react-grid-Cell:nth-child(2) "
          },
          {
            content:
              "This column has been configured to listen to an onContextMeny event. When the cell is right clicked, a message will be logged to the console",
            target: ".react-grid-Cell:nth-child(25) "
          }
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
```

main.js

```js
        <ReactDataGrid
            columns={this.state.columns}
            rowGetter={i => this.state.rows[i]}
            rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
            onGridRowsUpdated={this.onGridRowsUpdated}
            enableCellSelect={true}
        />
        <PageGuide />
```

When I add PageGuide in the main react file it removes my table scroll abillity, anyone might have a clue why?

Comment: Video: https://www.loom.com/share/6c841991bf234adba16e0344457a2e80

Answer (score 0):

[I found resolve here](https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride/issues/563)
You wait a lot of time for answer and you get it

use disableScrollParentFix

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31352966)